# Win32_PnPEntity not getting hidden devices

Tags: windows, wmi

I'm using the Win32_PnPEntity class to get all the devices in a computer, but the Win32_PnPEntity class does not list the hidden devices. Hidden devices in the Windows device manager have a status "Currently, this hardware device is not connected to the computer. (Code 45)" and can be shown by clicking the menu option in Device Manager: View > Show hidden devices (Windows 10).

Does anyone know how to get the hidden devices?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using the command:

```
Get-PnpDevice -class "Ports"

Status     Class           FriendlyName
------     -----           ------------                                                                         
OK         Ports           Communications Port (COM1)                                                           
Unknown    Ports           Silicon Labs Dual CP2105 USB to UART Bridge: Enhanced  
Unknown    Ports           Arduino Uno (COM5)                                                               
Unknown    Ports           Silicon Labs Dual CP2105 USB to UART Bridge: Standard 
OK         Ports           Prolific USB-to-Serial Comm Port (COM6)
```

Here you can see my COM ports that have been disconnected (status: unknown)

Comment: Thanks @bck, I needed that answer, like 5 years ago! 

Comment: Nice Get-PnpDevice lists hidden devices. Wondering how they are doing it behind the scenes.  Is it possible to use WMI direct (like in C#) to do same thing.  So far can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason unknown to me, it appears that Microsoft has hardcoded Win32_PnpEntity on the backend to return non-'OK' devices only when using Get-PnpDevice. You can emulate this behavior by setting a special CIM option called 'MI_OPERATIONOPTIONS_POWERSHELL_CMDLETNAME' to contain the value '-PnpDevice' (e.g. 'Get-PnpDevice'). This will work outside of PowerShell (i.e. in other languages) if you are using the CIM libraries/functions that support setting CIM options. I do not believe, however, there is any way to set this variable in a raw WMI query unfortunately.

```
$CimSession = New-CimSession
$Options = [Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.Options.CimOperationOptions]::new()
$Options.SetOption('MI_OPERATIONOPTIONS_POWERSHELL_CMDLETNAME','XXX-PnpDevice')
$CimSession.EnumerateInstances('ROOT/CIMV2','Win32_PnpEntity',$Options) | Where-Object 'Status' -ne 'OK'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `ConfigManagerErrorCode`. Refer [Win32_PnPEntity](http://www.powertheshell.com/reference/wmireference/root/cimv2/win32_pnpentity/) and [Win32_PnPEntity MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394353(v=vs.85).aspx). You have not mentioned if you are using powershell or C# for scripting, i am assuming powershell.

```
$result = @{Expression = {$_.Name}; Label = "Device Name"},
          @{Expression = {$_.ConfigManagerErrorCode} ; Label = "Status Code" }

    Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PnpEntity -ComputerName localhost -Namespace Root\CIMV2 | Where-Object {$_.ConfigManagerErrorCode -gt 0 } | Format-Table $result
```

Comment: Hi Amit. The code you put here is returning the disabled devices and not the hidden devices. The hidden devices are devices that have been connected before, but aren't currently connected.
In Windows 10 (maybe only Windows 10?) open Device Manager and click the menu View > Show hidden devices. Under Network adapters you will see WAN Miniports that were hidden before and under storage volumes you will see hidden (USB) volumes.

Comment: Try : {$_.ConfigManagerErrorCode -eq 45 }

And can you get the output for below mentioned query, if first one does not work.
 Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PnpEntity | Export-CSV C:\<filename>.csv

Comment: Win32_PnpEntity just doesn't output hidden devices. That's the whole thing.

Comment: How can get this command inC# ? Get-PnpDevice -class "Ports"